# Laplace mechanism in Differential Privacy

Tags: differential-privacy

From [The Algorithmic Foundations of Diﬀerential Privacy](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~aaroth/Papers/privacybook.pdf)
It wrote that :

[image]

But from this [pdf](https://www.seas.upenn.edu/~cis399/files/lecture/l21.pdf)

[image]

I am confused which one is right, or I misunderstand.

In second method, after I compute Pr[v], and then what to do?

I am not sure how to implement the Laplace mechanism.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**These two formulas are the same thing**. The second formula is the probability density function of the [Laplace distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_distribution#Probability_density_function) centered on 0 ($\mu=0$) — although rather than $Pr[v]$, the second PDF should probably have used a notation like $f(v)$ to make it clear that this is a probability density function and not the probability of returning exactly $v$.

If the question about "how to implement the Laplace mechanism" was referring to something you want to do in practice, then *you probably don't want to do it yourself*; but you want to use an implementation safe against [floating-point attacks](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/lsbs.pdf). Here's an [example](https://github.com/google/differential-privacy) of open-source software you can use (disclaimer: I'm part of the team behind that library).

Answer (score 0):

If I would see both I would have the same misunderstanding you had. I got a little late but in order to connect ideas we have $v = x$ where $v \in Y_i$ and $\mathcal{M}_L = f(x)+v$. What I see here is a bad notation on the last one, since $v$ is a point, not a distribution as $Y_i$. This should be something like $V_i \sim Lap(\Delta f / \epsilon)$ where you want to know $Pr[V=v]$.

Then I always going to prefer the full notation of Laplace and function which is $Lap(\mu,b)$ which has a mean of $\mu$ and a variance of $2b$. Now the probability of $x$ in Laplace is $Lap(x \mid (\mu,b))$.

$$Lap(x \mid (\mu,b))=\frac{1}{2b}e^{\frac{-|x-\mu|}{b}}$$

What you want to compute is the $f(x)$ with the noise. If you only are going to compute the noise then you should use only $Pr[v]=Pr[Y=x]$ (Remember $x=v$). What you want to compute is $\mathcal{M}_L(x)$. Which by definition (now this is why is useful the mean notation) is :

$$\mathcal{M}_L(x \mid (\mu,b))=\frac{1}{2b}e^{\frac{-\varepsilon|x-f(x)|}{\Delta f}}$$

Because you only move the distribution to the left by $f(x)$. Then you have :[image]

If you want to implement the mechanism you can obtain the query $f(x)$ from a Database and using a library that has Laplace distribution do $\mathcal{M}_L(x) = f(x)+ Y_i$ where $Y_i \sim Lap(\Delta f / \epsilon)$. Remember $x$ is the database and $f(x) \in \mathbb{R}^k$